# C++ CGI nowadays

Tags: php, c++, cgi, fastcgi

[image]
<sub>(source: [atmel.com](http://www.atmel.com/Images/compiler.jpg))</sub>

**Background**

I've a 5 years PHP background and in the last month I've been busy finding a way to do web with C++ (even if I know this is childish and stupid, I feel like C++ is the only true programming language and I have this sort of religious faith in it that makes me love it and only it).

**My CGI trip**

I've come across several blog posts (mostly from 2000-2003), discussions and had some chat discussions here. This is what I've gathered:

- PHP is designed for the web while C++ is a generic purpose language.
- PHP is inconsistent and have a lot of hate on the web
- PHP is the most common and supported scripting language out there
- CGI is a pretty old and *common* technology that was used in the days before PHP (PHP1 was actually a CGI library for C)
- In CGI (vs PHP) we have the problem of the `fork-exec` execution for each process which kinda slows everything down
- ^ this is what FastCGI is there for
- For some common mathematic operations C++ is 200X faster than PHP (because of PHP being an interpreted language)
- Big websites that requires performance doesn't use pure PHP (Facebook use HipHop which is something related to C++ and on Google there are several rumors about it being written in Perl, C++, C or some other language but PHP)
- PHP is faster to learn and to write
- C++ has very bad string manipulation methods
- There are some good (subjective) libraries for C++ CGI like wT (witty).
- Some people just told me to stay away from PHP as far as I could

**Real question(s)**

Today I have to decide whatever to go with PHP or CGI. And I'm asking you:

1. Is CGI dead in 2013? (yeah I know it has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464652/is-cgi-dead))
2. Since everybody needs performance and considering that I've time to spend like 1 year to build a solid C++ library for the web and that I don't like easy things, what are the cons in using CGI (or FCGI) nowadays (in comparison to newer techonologies)
3. Is there a more efficient way to build websites with C++
4. What is the real deal with FastCGI?
5. Is FastCGI widely supported?
6. Considering a project where I have to build a web tool, web app, iphone app, pc app and mac app all around a single website/server/database, can I actually reuse some code from the C++ website for my applications? (the database interaction for example)?

Comment: Way too many questions here, not many of them actually answerable. Please focus on a _specific_ programming issue at a time.

Comment: I usually use PHP via CGI, so that I can get a handle on the user as which the interpreter runs for userdirs. CGI is just a protocol...

Comment: "I feel like C++ is the only true programming language" - [You're mistaken.](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57643/focus=57918)

Comment: For 3 I would answer programming your site inside the source of a HTTP daemon, with no protocols.

Comment: @H2CO3, "From: Linus Torvalds <torvalds <at> linux-foundation.org>" - not reading from that point on, I'm trying not to read bullshits written by that troll. edit: well, I've read a bit of it, and he is right in only one point - people unable to program are trying to program. But that is true for every programming language that is used out there, therefore cannot be used as an argument for not using one particular one.

Comment: C++11 is much better than C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Almost used for only very specific cases
2. Don't build one use one: CppCMS*
3. Yes, C++ Web Frameworks
4. Because it is dead for a long time ago
5. It replaces CGI making it VERY efficient
6. Yes - all major (and minor) web servers support it

`* Full-disclosure: I am the author`